# Performing Unit Testing for UX

Tags: usability-testing

I have a tricky question and I'm not sure if calling it "unit testing" is the right thing to do as I am by no means a UX person - I am learning a lot though.

I have a website and I'm trying to perform unit testing on the user experience, if that's possible.

For example, everytime the backend is updated, I want to ensure that the user experience doesn't change in order to make sure the system is running smoothly. In this way, it is a unit-testing framework but not at the source code level.

What kind of frameworks can help with this?

Comment: Sounds like you maybe are looking for "UI Regression Testing"

Comment: Another term for this is "functional testing" or "GUI testing". Selenium is a popular one for web related testing. Here's a list of other tools: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GUI_testing_tools

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium to write automated web tests. However this can be quite expensive and brittle, and might not pick up on UX concerns such as text overruns.

Another way might be to have a 'demonstration page' that uses all of the key css for your application. You could create a snapshot of this demonstration page and play spot the difference after each build/release to see if anything has unexpectedly changed. This could be automated by saving the page as a .jpg and getting software to find differences.

Regardless it is likely for some degree of ongoing manual UX testing to be needed. As UX 'feel' can be quite subjective.